# cant resize buttons in customtkinter

Tags: customtkinter

i have a little project in custumetkinter for simplicity lets say that my code:

```
 customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")
        customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
        root = customtkinter.CTk()
        root.title("root title")
        root.geometry("300x330")
        
        main_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text="button", width = 30, height = 100, font=("Roboto", 16),     command=open_file_dialog)
        main_button.pack(pady=150)
```

the problem is the button is made in size by the text size inside of it, Regardless on the width and height  parameters.

the row: main_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text="button", width = 200, height = 500, font=("Roboto", 16), command=open_file_dialog) will give me the same button.

if you can help me modify my button, it will be great. thx!

the documantation of the library describe these paremeters need to change the size of the button. i dont really know what to do.

trying to run another script and run this again, didnt help.